# how to disable http methods via iis

Tags: iis, http

We have unnecessary http methods enabled on one of our servers, and have been advised to disable any methods we do not require. The problem I have is that I am unsure of how to disable the unused methods. Can anyone provide an example or walkthrough on how to-do this ?

We are using a windows 2003 std server running IIS6

Answer (score 1):

It's in the Application Extension Mappings:

1. Right-click your site or virtual directory and get properties
2. Click the Home Directory or Virtual Directory tab
3. Click the Configuration button
4. On the Mappings tab choose an extension / mapping and click Edit
5. In the Verbs pane, select the Limit To radio button and enter only the HTTP verbs you want to allow at that site / virtual directory level